# backbone Finding the current page

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a built in call to find out the current page, in a bootstrap environment.. I am trying to hide some of the links depending on the page i am on. 
we have a router as follows;

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        // Define some URL routes
        'login' : 'showLogin',
        'main' : 'showMain',
        'faq' : 'showFaq
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563949/backbone-js-get-current-route

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for the last route triggered in the router then you can access it using

```
Backbone.history.fragment
```

Provided history was started after initializing routers.

Comment: there is a typo : it is fragment and not fragement